# Git adding only one of my folders instead of all of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, github

I have a node and react project.

I created a folder called project and my subfolders are client and server

I ran create-react-app in the client and npm init -y in the server

When in in the project directory

I git init

Then git add .

I get this error

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.

hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of

hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.

hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:

hint: 

hint:   git submodule add <url> client

hint: 

hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the

hint: index with:

hint: 

hint:   git rm --cached client

hint: 

hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Nothing inside my client folder commits.

Please help.

Edit: I basically had two git initializations in the same folder. In order to solve this I just had to delete one of those initializations. I did so by enabling the viewing of my hidden files and deleting one of the .git files.

Comment: Probably need to see the folder structure honestly. Can you screenshot from the root of the project in VS Code please?

Comment: It looks like your project contains another Git repository. Try adding that repo folder to `.gitignore` file or give Git Submodule a try: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: do you want to create sub repositories inside your current repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create-react-app` automatically initializes `git` for you. If you're on Windows, Go to View and enable the option to view hidden files. On Linux, you can already see the directory if I'm not mistaken.
Then in your `client` directory, delete the `.git` folder.

Now you can `git init` in the root i.e. in the `project` directory and you're good to go.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!